# angularjs ui-grid restrict enableSelectAll to only select entries on the page size

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

I want to restrict the select all functionlity to not select the entire data set, but instead only select entries displayed on the page. How can this be done?

```
$scope.gridEvents = {
  enableSorting :           true,
  enableSelectAll:          true,
  enableColumnResize:       true,
  enablePaginationControls: false,
  rowHeight:                27,
  enableScrollbars :        true,
  paginationPageSize :      10
}
```

Comment: If your grid is using paging this should be the default. If you are not using paging and showing every row of data, then how are you defining  "displayed on the page"?

Comment: displayed on the page is basically subset of data which is defined by   paginationPageSize :      10